# getting count of missing values in summary

Tags: r, expss

i want to get the count of NA's in column with max and min. is there any way in expss already to get a count in below example

```
library(expss)
library(dplyr)

example <- data.frame(org = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"),
                      q1 = c("apple", "apple", NA, "apple", "apple", "apple", NA),
                      q2 = c(NA, NA, NA, "banana", "banana", "banana", NA),
                      q3 = c("orange", NA, "orange", "orange", NA, "orange", NA),
                      region = c("1", "1", "2", "3", "3", "2", "2"))

pct_all <- cross_cpct(example, mrset(q1 %to% q3), region)
```

Comment: Could you clarify how you got the missing values in the "missing Vals" in your output? In your example data I am seeing n =3 in region 1, n = 5 in region 2, and n = 1 in region 3 for missing values

Comment: that is just a temp required output

Comment: I maybe have a (real dirty) solution. hope I get it right want you wanted do like: example1 <-example %>%  mutate_all(., as.factor) %>% mutate_all(., as.numeric)
navalues <- example1 %>% 
  group_by(region, q1) %>% 
  summarise(naq2 = sum(is.na(q2)),
            naq3 = sum(is.na(q3))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(region) %>% 
  summarize(missing_val_1 = sum(naq2, naq3, na.rm = TRUE))
rbind(pct_all, c("missing", navalues$missing_val_1))